# implement abstract method 'getDataBinder(DataBindingComponent, View, int)' in 'DataBinderMapper'

Tags: android

```
public class DataBinderMapperImpl extends DataBinderMapper {
  private static final SparseIntArray INTERNAL_LAYOUT_ID_LOOKUP = new SparseIntArray(0);

  @Override
  public ViewDataBinding getDataBinder(DataBindingComponent component, View view, int layoutId) {
    int localizedLayoutId = INTERNAL_LAYOUT_ID_LOOKUP.get(layoutId);
    if(localizedLayoutId > 0) {
      final Object tag = view.getTag();
      if(tag == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("view must have a tag");
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public ViewDataBinding getDataBinder(DataBindingComponent component, View[] views, int layoutId) {
    if(views == null || views.length == 0) {
      return null;
    }
    int localizedLayoutId = INTERNAL_LAYOUT_ID_LOOKUP.get(layoutId);
    if(localizedLayoutId > 0) {
      final Object tag = views[0].getTag();
      if(tag == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("view must have a tag");
      }
      switch(localizedLayoutId) {
      }
    }
    return null;
```

I tried re_syncing the gradle and also enabled this

dataBinding {
enabled = true

but still error

Class 'DataBinderMapperImpl' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'getDataBinder(DataBindingComponent, View, int)' in 'DataBinderMapper'

Method does not override method from its superclass 21